# Invoke function with new operator as argument

Tags: javascript

As known, when we applying `new` operator to function

```
function foo(){ ... }
```

an empty object `{}` will be created initially. Further funcion foo() will be invoked as a method of just created empty object. Thus `this` will be get a reference to this empty object.

Now consider the following `HTML`:

```
<div id="parent" class="parent">
    <div id="child" class="child">
        <input type="text" class="text"/>
        <input id="submit" value="submit" type="submit" onclick="doThis()"/>
    </div>
<div>
```

and corresponding `JS` code:

```
function doThis(){
    myKeys=[];
    var span= document.createElement("span");
    var parent=document.getElementById("parent");
    var child=document.getElementById("child");
    var submit=document.getElementById("submit");
    child.insertBefore(span,submit.nextSibling);
    span.innerHTML= getAllKeyValuePair(new test()); //Why this line returned {prop,property} rather then {0, H}, {1,e}, {2,l}, {3,l}, {4,o}
}

function getAllKeyValuePair(obj){
    var str="";
    for(var key in obj){
        try{
            str=str+"{"+key+", "+obj[key]+"}";
        }
        catch(e){
            console.log(key);
        }
    }

    return str;
}

function test(){
    this.prop="property";
    return "Hello";
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bundos/BYwz9/14/)**. I'm expected that the `span` will be contains `{0, H}, {1,e}, {2,l}, {3,l}, {4,o}` because after creating an empty object `test()` will be invoked just as a method of this object and returned `"Hello"`, but it is not true. Please explain me how it works?

Comment: Only a returned **object**, will *override* the newly created one. This does not work with literals. Try [`return new String('Hello');`](http://jsfiddle.net/5aXcK/1/) instead.

Comment: @Yoshi Thanks for your comment. It's very interesting, but can you explain what did you do this exactly this way?

Comment: It's just a way to explicitly create (and return) a string as an object, not as a literal. I'd post this as an answer, if I could find an official reference to what I'm saying. Maybe someone else has better luck finding one ;)